# Web application starter kit

Tags: html, css, web, web-applications, project-setup

I am looking for a site that allows you to input a project name, choose a doctype, a js library etc. and then generates the directory structure and files to start a web project. I know about project deploy, but it is no longer maintained. There was a new one that was created within the last 2 or 3 months, but for the life of me I can't find it either through Google nor my delicious bookmarks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After several hours of digging through my bookmarks. I finally found it here: instantblueprint.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on **Web Application Starter Kit** (aka Site SDK) built on top of the ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework, Windows Azure...

You can check it's status here: http://github.com/kriasoft/site-sdk